# sql variable declaration

Tags: oracle

I am trying to declare a variable in workbench using an oracle db. I found two approaches which both don't seem to be recognized as workbench does not highlight either var nor define as command

```
define s = 'test'
SELECT &&s from dual
;

var s varchar(max)
exec: s := 'test'
SELECT &&s from dual
```

both throw an error 1064. You ahve an error in your sql syntax.

How can I declare a simple variable to do something like

```
x = 'test'
select * from t where y = x
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.

When in PL/SQL, you have to declare it like this:

```
declare
  l_s varchar2 := 'test';
begin
  select l_s
  into   some_other_var
  from   dual
  ;
  -- or
  some_other_var := l_s;
end;
;
```

Or, when simply using in a query:

```
select :s
from   dual
```

This will ask you for the value of `s`.

Comment: @chrise: Need more help?